# Progress in SeekBar and EditText with LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have TextInput, and SeekBar.

I Need to change seeker's value by text input value (numeric), and change the text value by seeker changed value. using View-Model and Live data binding

So, I have two mediator live datas in viewmodel class

**ViewModel:**

```
val progress: MediatorLiveData<Int> by lazy { MediatorLiveData<Int>() }
val progressText: MediatorLiveData<String> by lazy { MediatorLiveData<String>() }
```

which are observed by each other in init scope.

```
init {
  progress.apply { addSource(progressText) { postValue(it.toInt()) }}
  progressText.apply { addSource(progress) { postValue(it.toString()) }}
}
```

And the xml and data-binding are like:

```
<AppCompatSeekBar android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            style="@style/SeekerItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="@={viewModel.progress}" />

 <EditText android:id="@+id/input_progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={viewModel.progressText}" />
```

[image]
(consider the text is input)

But, here i got infinite loop, because one mediator's changes affect to other's and the other's change comes back to one.

Are here best practice and more clever solutions to solve this logic? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need a `MediatorLiveData` here - `MutableLiveData` is enough because you just need to be able to change values.
2. It's enough to have only one `LiveData` for `progress` and it should hold an `Int` value inside.

Now the code:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

open class BasicViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val progress: MutableLiveData<Int> by lazy { MutableLiveData<Int>() }
}
```

And your layout could look like below (please note how `viewModel.progress` is converted to `String` for `EditText`)

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="BasicViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/input_progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="@={`` + viewModel.progress}" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="@={viewModel.progress}" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Finally, your `Activity` could be as follows:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
                this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BasicViewModel::class.java)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If the text in the `EditText` is not identical to values in `SeekBar` then the approach will be different.  However, it's still enough to have one `LiveData<charSequence>` object to implement such scenario. So, let's imagine that `EditText` should show a float value like `progress/100`. Then, it could look like as below:

**BasicViewModel.kt**

```
package com.example.android.databinding.basicsample.data

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

open class BasicViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val progressLiveData = MutableLiveData("0.0")

    fun updateEditText(percentage: Int) {
        progressLiveData.value = percentage.toFloat().div(100).toString()
    }

    fun onEditTextTyped(): LiveData<Int> {
        return Transformations.switchMap(progressLiveData, {
            val liveData = MutableLiveData<Int>()
            try {
                liveData.value = it.toString().toFloat().times(100f).toInt()
            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                // reset the progress bar if the progress text is invalid
                liveData.value = 0
            }
            liveData
        })
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.android.databinding.basicsample.data.BasicViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={viewModel.progressLiveData}" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="@{viewModel.onEditTextTyped}"
            android:onProgressChanged="@{(seekBar, progress, fromUser) -> viewModel.updateEditText(progress)}" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Transformations.distinctUntilChanged(liveData)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations.html#distinctUntilChanged(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E))

Creates a new LiveData object that does not emit a value until the source LiveData value has been changed. The value is considered changed if equals() yields false.

So by using `distinctUntilChanged`, we can stop your infinite loop by checking if the value of the source live data has changed or not.

---

If you are using **livedata-ktx** library you can use below code

```
init {
   progress.apply { addSource(progressText.distinctUntilChanged()) { postValue(it.toInt()) }}
   progressText.apply { addSource(progress.distinctUntilChanged()) { postValue(it.toString()) }}
}
```

---

If you are not using **livedata-ktx** library you can use below code

```
init {
   progress.apply { addSource(Transformations.distinctUntilChanged(progressText)) { postValue(it.toInt()) }}
   progressText.apply { addSource(Transformations.distinctUntilChanged(progress)) { postValue(it.toString()) }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make 2 pairs of MediatorLiveData-LiveData for the seeker and for the text respectively. For example, the 1st MediatorLiveData observes changes of the seek bar and when changes are applied, it changes LiveData of the EditText and vice versa: you have MediatorLiveData that changes LiveData of the SeekBar every time something is changed in the EditText.